# How do I maximize memory usage using powershell

Tags: testing, memory, powershell

I am trying do some testing that requires resources to be under pressure. I was able to find out how maximize CPU Usage using PowerShell.

```
start-job -ScriptBlock{
$result = 1; 
foreach ($number in 1..2147483647) 
    {
        $result = $result * $number
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can use PowerShell to do the same for maximizing memory usage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
$mem_stress = "a" * 200MB
```

**Edit:** If cou can't allocate all memory in a single chunk, try allocating multiple chunks in an array:

```
$mem_stress = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt ###; $i++) { $mem_stress += ("a" * 200MB) }
```

The GC doesn't seem to interfere with this (results from a quick test in a VM with 1 GB RAM assigned):

```
PS C:\> $a = @()
PS C:\> $a += ("a" * 200MB)
PS C:\> $a += ("a" * 200MB)
PS C:\> $a += ("a" * 200MB)
PS C:\> $a += ("a" * 200MB)
The '*' operator failed: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown..
At line:1 char:13
+ $a += ("a" * <<<<  200MB)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperatorFailed
```

Comment: This is a neat trick, but this fails when `1024MB` or greater, which means this alone isn't enough to stress most machines. Using this idea, I'd put it in a `for()` loop to continually chew up memory, but I'm not certain how much the GC will negate this.

Comment: This: for ($i = 0; $i < ###; $i++) { $mem_stress += ("a" * 200MB) }
Should be this: for ($i = 0; $i -lt ###; $i++) { $mem_stress += ("a" * 200MB) }

Comment: @user1161625 Indeed it should. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.